# How to create AWS glue job using CLI commands?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

How can we create a glue job using CLI commands? Can I have one sample code?Thanks!

Comment: What you have tried? What problems are you experiencing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to this [link](https://dev.classmethod.jp/articles/my-first-glue-by-cli/) which talks about creating AWS Glue resources using CLI. This blog is in Japanese. Following is the sample to create a Glue job using CLI.

```
aws glue create-job \
    --name ${GLUE_JOB_NAME} \
    --role ${ROLE_NAME} \
    --command "Name=glueetl,ScriptLocation=s3://${SCRIPT_BUCKET_NAME}/${ETL_SCRIPT_FILE}" \
    --connections Connections=${GLUE_CONN_NAME} \
    --default-arguments file://${DEFAULT_ARGUMENT_FILE}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow documentation and post error if any
Link to docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glue/create-job.html